# Build MariaDB 10.5 on Raspberry Pi 3B Unable to find a source package for mariadb-server

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os-buster, mariadb

I am wanting to build [MariaDB 10.5.5](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/10.5.5/) on my Raspberry Pi 3B (Kernel version 5.4.65-v7+) since it has some nice features I want to play with. The first step involves setting up the build environment described here: [Build Environment Setup for Linux](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/Build_Environment_Setup_for_Linux/)

However the first step used to install all the dependencies doesn't work:

```
 sudo apt build-dep mariadb-server
 Reading package lists... Done
 E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

The documentation is aware of this problem and asks that you include the source repositories in your `sources.list` file:

> Note: On Debian-based distributions, you may receive a "You must put
> some 'source' URIs in your sources.list" error. To avoid this, ensure
> that /etc/apt/sources.list contains the source repositories.

So I uncommented the `deb-src` command from my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

```
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ buster main
```

After saving the changes and running `sudo apt-get update` I then get the following error after running `apt build-dep mariadb-server`:

```
sudo apt build-dep mariadb-server
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'mariadb-10.3' as source package instead of 'mariadb-server'
E: Unable to find a source package for mariadb-server
```

Does anyone know how I can run `apt build-dep mariadb-server` for MariaDB 10.5?

Comment: Did `sudo apt update` after changing the apt source file run without errors? BTW: you will not get the 10.5.5 source from the RPF repo. As the msg said the version there is 10.3.3. You will probably have to use the sources from the mariadb website.

Comment: No errors occurred after running `sudo apt update`. I realise now that installing the dependencies using `apt build-dep` only works if the package is already available for your distro. Are there any other commands that I could use to install all the required dependencies when the package hasn't been built yet for Raspberry Pi OS? I should then be able to build from source once I have all the dependencies.

Comment: The DEB Package Debian/Ubuntu (x86, x86_64, ppc64el, arm64) has "DEB Package Debian/Ubuntu (x86, x86_64, ppc64el, arm64)" and claims to have versions for Debian 8 (Stretch) (sic) & Debian 9 (Jessie) (sic). There is no indication that ANYONE has built for Buster or ARM - so your chances are slim.

Comment: [Arch Linux ARM](https://archlinuxarm.org/about) has been successful with building MariaDB 10.5 on ARM [mariadb 10.5.5-2](https://archlinuxarm.org/packages/armv7h/mariadb) so with any luck I can build it on Buster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mariadb is available, just not in the version you want.  The reason that `build-dep` doesn't work is possibly because `mariadb-server` is actually a ["metapackage depending on the latest version"](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=mariadb&searchon=names&suite=stable&section=all) (latest in the repo that is, not the universe as a whole); the actual binaries are in `mariadb-server-10.3`.

You don't actually need the source from the repo of course, because you won't be using it, you'll be using the source for 10.5 you download from somewhere.  However, `build-dep` seems useful if you don't know how to sort such things out yourself (and may save some time even if you do).  Most likely, they should be fine to use to build 10.5, so try `apt build-dep mariadb-server-10.3`.